# SQL Server how to delete a row if a value equals to a value in the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've tried to write it but it didn't work.

I have a table called `files` and a column called `Username` and a string called `str`.

I want a simple thing - if the `str` equals to anything in the `Username` column, then delete it (there can not be double values, so don't worry about that).

I wrote it like that:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM files WHERE Username = @username) 
BEGIN 
     DELETE FROM files 
     WHERE Username = @username
```

@username = str

It doesn't work, I hope you can assist.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work does not provide information. Did you get an error message? Did it delete too many/not enough rows? Was is supposed to insert rows instead? This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to check whether any rows exist:

```
DELETE FROM [files] WHERE Username = @username
```

If there are no rows, they won't be deleted!